# Three ways to add pronoun method/property to gendered class in Python

Tags: python

Say you have a Python class for something that has an optional gender field. You'd like a helper property/method to get the appropriate pronoun for an instance. You'd also like to be able to get the possessive version of the pronoun. The use for these helpers will be in creating human-readable emails and other such messages related to the object.

Below are three ways to do it. Which is best in terms of style and design and why?

**Option 1**

```
@property
def pronoun(self):
    return "he" if self.gender == 'male' else "she" if self.gender == 'female' else "they"

@property
def possessive_pronoun(self):
    return "his" if self.gender == 'male' else "her" if self.gender == 'female' else "their"
```

**Option 2**

```
def pronoun(self, possessive=False):
    if possessive:
        return "his" if self.gender == 'male' else "her" if self.gender == 'female' else "their"
    else:
        return "he" if self.gender == 'male' else "she" if self.gender == 'female' else "they"
```

**Option 3**

```
def pronoun(self, possessive=False):
    pronouns = ("he", "his") if self.gender == 'male' else ("she", "her") if self.gender == 'female' \
        else ("they", "their")
    return pronouns[1] if possessive else pronouns[0]
```

Feel free to suggest an even better fourth option.

P.S. In case you are wondering, I like to use double quotes for strings meant for human consumption, single quotes otherwise.

Comment: In any case, the correct spelling seems to be "possessive" and not "possesive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 looks to be best in my opinion as it enforces readability of the intent in the instance usage, e.g.

```
u.subject_pronoun.capitalize() + " is buying the new widget for " + u.possesive_pronoun + " own use."
```

Versus:

```
u.pronoun().capitalize() + " is buying the new widget for " + u.pronoun(True) + " own use."
```

In the latter case the meaning is lost on the possessive pronoun since the consumer of the class didn't supply the argument name.

Another approach to getting the values by a nested dictionary (similar to the Ruby way suggested by Josay) would be:

```
self._pronouns = {
    'male': {
        'possessive': 'his',
        'object': 'him',
        'subject': 'he'
        },

    'female': {
        'possessive': 'hers',
        'object': 'her',
        'subject': 'she'
        },

    'unspecified': {
        'possessive': 'theirs',
        'object': 'them',
        'subject': 'they'
        }
    }
@property
def object_pronoun(self):
   return self._pronouns[self.gender]['object'] if self.gender else self._pronouns['unspecified']['object']
def possessive_pronoun(self):
   return self._pronouns[self.gender]['possessive'] if self.gender else self._pronouns['unspecified']['possessive']
def subject_pronoun(self):
   return self._pronouns[self.gender]['subject'] if self.gender else self._pronouns['unspecified']['subject']
```

This approach allows for more types to be added easily as shown by adding the subject type.

Edit: Updated per comment suggestions.

Comment: I agree, option 1 is the best of the three interfaces. I would go even further and rename `pronoun` →  `nominative_pronoun`. There should be another case as well: [`object_pronoun`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pronoun). (You seem to have changed nominative case in the question to objective case in your answer.)

Comment: You've used the key `plural` for the third case (*their* / *theirs*). But the OP indicates that the gender field is optional, so the third case is really *unspecified* or *other*, not *plural*.

Answer (score 3):

I usually try to use data structure over code whenever it's possible.
It usually make things shorter, easier to read and easier to update.

If I had to write such a thing, I'd probably write something like (untested code but just to show the idea) :

```
pronouns = {
    'male' => ("he","his"),
    'female' => ("she", "her")
}

def pronoun(self, possessive=False):
    return pronouns.get(self.gender, default=("they","their"))[possessive]
```

If we could be sure that self.gender has only 3 different values, the default value could be put in the `pronouns` dictionnary straightaway (associated to `"plural"` for instance).

Different variations could be written. I guess one could use `defaultdict` to ensure that we always retrieve the default value. I don't like this solution that much as the dictionnary would get bigger as we try to retrieve using invalid keys.

I don't know if there's a (simple) way to have a dictionnary which returns a default value when the key is not present without updating the dictionnary but I'd be interested in such a thing.

Comment: `=>` should be `:`? and can't use `possessive` directly as a key value, right?

Comment: That's Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 2):

From a style perspective I like the first option; if you're treating this as a property its clear what you intend

For implementation, I'd try a class level default with an instance override to provide the right words to allow for specialization or extension (for other languages than English, say, or use at Oberlin College).  Whatever your gender politics this implementation is extensible to new cases and one offs.

```
class Gendered(object):
    NOMINATIVE = {'m':('he', 'they'), 'f': ('she','they'), 'n':('it', 'they')}
    ACCUSATIVE = {'m':('him', 'them'), 'f': ('her','them'), 'n':('it', 'them')}
    POSSESSIVE = {'m':('his', 'their'), 'f': ('hers', 'their'), 'n':('its', 'their')}

    def __init__(self, word, gender = 'n', plural = 0, **kwargs):
        self.Word = word
        self.Gender = gender.lower()[0]
        self.Plural = 0 if not plural else 1
        self.Nominative = kwargs.get('nominative', self.NOMINATIVE)
        self.Accusative = kwargs.get('accusative', self.ACCUSATIVE)
        self.Posessive = kwargs.get('possessive', self.POSSESSIVE)

    def get_pronoun(self, case ):  # where case will be one of self.Nominative. self.Accusative, self.Possesive
        return case.get(self.Gender, ('',''))[self.Plural]
        # using get rather than if-checking lets you specify a default

    @property
    def pronoun(self):
        return self.get_pronoun(self.Nominative);

    @property
    def accusative_pronoun(self):
        return self.get_pronoun(self.Accusative);
    @property
    def possessive_pronoun(self):
        return self.get_pronoun(self.Posessive);


example = Gendered("battleship", "f", False)
print example.pronoun
print example.accusative_pronoun
print example.possessive_pronoun

example = Gendered("king", "m", possessive = {'m':('his royal', 'their royal'), 'f':('her royal', 'their royal'), 'n':('their', 'their royal')})
print example.pronoun
print example.accusative_pronoun
print example.possessive_pronoun
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's no longer 2014, it's possible to use dataclasses:

```py
@dataclass
class Pronouns:
    subject: str
    object: str
    possessive: str

    @classmethod
    @property
    def they_their(cls):
        return cls("they", "them", "their")

    @classmethod
    @property
    def she_her(cls):
        return cls("she", "her", "hers")

    @classmethod
    @property
    def he_him(cls):
        return cls("he", "him", "his")
```

You'd probably use this as a component of another class:

````py
@dataclass
class BarPatron:
    names: List[str]
    pronouns: Pronouns
    description: str

billiam = BarPatron(
    ["William", "Bill", "Billy", "Mac", "Buddy"],
    Pronouns.he_him,
    "man",
)

def sing_verse_one(patron):
    print(f"/"All I want to do is have a little fun before I die,/"")
    print(f"Says the {patron.description}, out of nowhere")
    print(f"It's apropos of nothing, but {patron.pronouns.subject} says "
          f"{patron.pronouns.possessive} name is {patron.names[0]}")
    print(f"But I'm sure it's {' or '.join(patron.names[1:])}")
```
````